# After installing package Quspin in Anaconda, it still says 'module not found"

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried installing the package Quspin following the windows instructions here:
http://weinbe58.github.io/QuSpin/Installation.html

I ran the "cmd.exe prompt" in anaconda and ran the command `conda install -c weinbe58 quspin`.
However, when I go to spyder and try running a simple line like `from quspin.operators import hamiltonian`, it says module quspin not found. When I go back to cmd.exe and get a list of the installed modules using `conda list`, it lists quspin as one of the packages, though it has a weird build label: "py37h45f375f_0". What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: did you restart the anaconda after installing?

Comment: Yes I did. I should add, when I go to "cmd.exe" in anaconda and then type "python" and run the line "help('modules'), quspin doesn't appear in the list of python modules there. However it still somehow appears in my list of anaconda packages.

Comment: i think you have installed module in a different virtual environment and running your script in a different environment

Comment: Is there some way I can check this?

Comment: yes,when you open the anaconda prompt in left side of the cmd it shows the current v-environment.you can activate different environment in anaconda gui as well

Comment: Under anadonra environments in the gui, it says I only have one environment called base (root).

Comment: if you have local python installation and if you open cmd and run a pip install,its install inside the local system.you should open base environment from the cmd or anaconda prompt and install package inside the base environment.

Comment: When I installed quspin, I did it through anaconda prompt and on the left it said (base). I believe the package is installed in the base environment.

Comment: yep.then it should work .try to reinstall and restart the environment and editor.

Comment: I uninstalled all versions of python and anaconda and reinstalled everything and it still isn't working unfortunately.

Comment: @Zach There are only a handful of packages which should be added to the base environment, as a rule of thumb create an environment for each project/application. You should reinstall Conda again, to ensure nothing is broken.